# Boot from USB stick, with old bios (no usb-boot option)?

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive, bootloader, bootable-media

Are there any ways to boot from USB stick on old PCs, whose BIOS doesn't have any USB-boot option?
do you know of any workarounds ?

ps: the BIOS is up-to-date.

Comment: CD's? When it come right down to it, "what the BIOS says, goes". Unless you flash it, but thats risky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the BIOS doesn't support boot from USB, the solution is to use a boot CD that can boot into USB:

[Boot From a USB Drive Even if your BIOS Won’t Let You](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/)